# Integrate $x^{3}e^{x}\int\frac{x+2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Integrate $$x^{3}e^{x}\int\frac{x+2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx$$

My attempt:
$$
x^{3}e^{x} \int \frac{1}{x^{2}e^{x}} + \frac{2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx =
x^{3}e^{x} \big[ \int \frac{2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx+ x^{-2}(-e^{-x}) - \int -2x^{-3}(-e^{-x})dx \big] 
$$
*I integrate by parts for the term $\int \frac{1}{x^2e^{x}}dx$*

Then
$$
= x^{3}e^{x} \big[ \int \frac{2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx - \frac{1}{x^{2}e^{x}} - \int \frac{2}{x^{3}e^{x}}dx \big]
=\frac{-x^{3}e^{x}}{x^{2}e^{x}}
= -x
$$

So, my answer is $-x$. But the answer given includes a constant: $-x + Cx^{3}e^{x}$.

Is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, there is a constant of integration ($C$) inside the bracket. So you first add $C$.

Comment: Where? I cancel the integrands out: $\int \frac{2}{x^{3}e^{x}}$.

Comment: There will be a constant associated with both indefinite integrals which *may or may not* be equal.

Comment: Consider  $ x+C_1$ and $ x+C_2$ both are antiderivatives of some function $f(x) = 1$. But we have that $(x+C_1) - (x+C_2) = C_1 - C_2$ which may not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $\int{f}(x)=F(x)$ and $\int{f}(x)=G(x)$, then can you say $\int{(f(x)-g(x))}=F(x)-G(x)=0$? Of course not.... Consider $f(x)=2sinxcosx$ and $g(x)=sin2x$ and integrate first one with integration by parts. See how the constant plays out...